# What are the mappings of unicode characters to the first 127 ASCII characters for the ascii folding token filter of ElasticSearch?

Tags: unicode, lucene, elasticsearch

Our product takes advantage of the ascii folding token filter and our customers are asking for specific information about it.  Specifically, they would like the mapping of unicode characters to the ASCII equivalent.  While I believe most conversions are obvious (e.g. ü = u), there are some "tricky" ones like ß, which I believe translates to "ss".

I've googled but have not been able to find a definitive mapping.  Is there some place I can get this information?

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Comment: [Related test code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_2/lucene/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TestASCIIFoldingFilter.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can just read the source code for `ASCIIFoldingFilter`.](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java)

A sample from that source:

```
      case '\u00C0': // À  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE]
      case '\u00C1': // Á  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE]
      case '\u00C2': // Â  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX]
      case '\u00C3': // Ã  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE]
      case '\u00C4': // Ä  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS]
      case '\u00C5': // Å  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE]
      case '\u0100': // Ā  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH MACRON]
      case '\u0102': // Ă  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE]
      case '\u0104': // Ą  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH OGONEK]
      case '\u018F': // Ə  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SCHWA]
      case '\u01CD': // Ǎ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CARON]
      case '\u01DE': // Ǟ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS AND MACRON]
      case '\u01E0': // Ǡ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOT ABOVE AND MACRON]
      case '\u01FA': // Ǻ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE AND ACUTE]
      case '\u0200': // Ȁ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOUBLE GRAVE]
      case '\u0202': // Ȃ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH INVERTED BREVE]
      case '\u0226': // Ȧ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOT ABOVE]
      case '\u023A': // Ⱥ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH STROKE]
      case '\u1D00': // ᴀ  [LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL A]
      case '\u1E00': // Ḁ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING BELOW]
      case '\u1EA0': // Ạ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DOT BELOW]
      case '\u1EA2': // Ả  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH HOOK ABOVE]
      case '\u1EA4': // Ấ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND ACUTE]
      case '\u1EA6': // Ầ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND GRAVE]
      case '\u1EA8': // Ẩ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND HOOK ABOVE]
      case '\u1EAA': // Ẫ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND TILDE]
      case '\u1EAC': // Ậ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND DOT BELOW]
      case '\u1EAE': // Ắ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE AND ACUTE]
      case '\u1EB0': // Ằ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE AND GRAVE]
      case '\u1EB2': // Ẳ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE AND HOOK ABOVE]
      case '\u1EB4': // Ẵ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE AND TILDE]
      case '\u1EB6': // Ặ  [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE AND DOT BELOW]
      case '\u24B6': // Ⓐ  [CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A]
      case '\uFF21': // Ａ  [FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A]
        output[outputPos++] = 'A';
        break;
```

As you can see, it doesn't do anything to Greek and Cyrillic letters, let alone other ones.

Also. as you guessed correctly, `ß` gets converted into `ss`:

```
      case '\u00DF': // ß  [LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S]
        output[outputPos++] = 's';
        output[outputPos++] = 's';
        break;
```